# How to filter multiple objects from a list objects by a property array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I have a object array in which each object contain an id and a name and a separate array contains a set of ids. I want to filter first array based on the second array.

```
const data= [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'name1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'name2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'name3'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'name4'
    }
];
```

```
const array = [1,3,4];

const expectedResult= [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'name1'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'name3'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'name4'
    }
];
```

Comment: Hi Trishan! Please try my solution below and let me know if it helps. If you find that it was helpful, please consider marking it as the solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.filter` and `.includes`

```js
    const data= [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'name1'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'name2'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'name3'
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'name4'
            }
        ];

    const array = [1, 3, 4] 
    
    const result = data.filter((item) => {

       //gives us items that passes a condition
       return array.includes(item.id)
     
    })
    
    console.log(result)
```